# Write a single output to terminal while sending everything else to a file

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm using `exec` to send all of a script's output to a file: `exec > file.errout 2>&1`. However, in the middle of the script I want to send a couple of messages to both the terminal and the file. I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash), but it requires flanking every terminal message with 2 lines of code and piping to `tee`:

```
exec > file.errout 2>&1
...
echo "messages only directed to the file"
...
exec >/dev/tty
echo "message i want directed to the terminal" | tee file.errout
exec > file.errout 2>&1
...
echo "more messages only directed to the file"
...
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to necessarily do that. After using `exec` to put all the stdout content to a file, just group the statements that you want to put to a terminal and `tee` it to `/dev/tty`

```
exec > file.errout 2>&1

echo "messages only directed to the file"

{
    echo "message i want directed to the terminal and file" ;
    echo "more more message i want directed to the terminal and file" ;
} | tee /dev/tty

echo "more messages only directed to the file"
```

You don't need to `exec >/dev/tty` everytime, because by virtue of your initial `exec` line all stdout is logged into the file.

Comment: I think this is the answer. I didn't realize I could pipe and `tee` to `/dev/tty`. The messages for the terminal are scattered throughout the code, but adding  `| tee /dev/tty` to each is easy enough.

Comment: @Josh: You should upvote and accept the answer to mark it resolved.

Comment: Yes, I know how SE works. I usually wait more than 12 hours from asking to accepting, in case a better answer arrives.

Answer (score 0):

In bash and zsh, you can try something like this:

```
exec >file.errout 2>&1
  # ...
exec {foo}>&1 > >(tee /dev/tty) 2>&1   # temporarily redirect
echo bla
ls no_such_file
exec >&$foo 2>&1                       # restore
  # ...
```

The `exec {var}>&1 ... exec >&$var` redirect/restore is similar to `exec 7>&1 .. exec >&7`, only that bash will itself get an unused file descriptor and store it in the `$var` variable, instead of you having to use some fixed number, which may conflict with the rest of code. This form of redirection is a ksh extension, also supported in bash and zsh.

The `exec > >(...)` redirection + process substitution combo, while practical, is subject to some quirks and bugs (and may not work in ksh93).

---

Of course, you may group the commands in a `{...}` block, and redirect the output of the whole block to a `| tee /dev/tty` pipe. That's the simplest and most portable.

The problem with it is that any variable assignments will happen in a subshell, not in your main script:

```
a=before
{
   a=$(pwd)
   # ...
} | tee /dev/tty
echo "$a"  #  still "before"
```